# How to split string which has no delimiter in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, split

I'm trying to split after the 16th character in Google Sheets. I tried using LEFT RIGHT & MID functions but not working.
For example
From 1 column trlr_id:
010810HARD01AFXNHV2202865
to 2 columns
010810HARD01AFXN & HV2202865

010810HARD01HJBBHMKD801679 to 010810HARD01HJBB & HMKD801679

Comment: I'm hoping to split after 16 characters on the left essentially

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=split(regexreplace(A1,"(.{16})","$1|"),"|")
```

[image]

For use in `pivot/calculated field(s)` use:

```js
=left(URL,16)
```

and

```js
=mid(URL,17,9^9)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this in a calculated field/pivot table (REGEXREPLACE isn't available in calculated column format)